# Dual-booting Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 and BackTrack 5 R3

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, backtrack

Does anyone have instructions as to how to dual-boot Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 and BackTrack 5 R3. I have Ubuntu already installed and would like to install BackTrack alongside it. I have found guides online for previous releases of both but wasn't sure if the set-up would be the same. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend, go directly install backtrack, remember, to have a manual partition, as you might have already have /swap space, or else you will end with double /swap, nothing is wrong with that, but, just waste of disk space. Set-up would be the same.